# How collapse several blocks with one button?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I have several revealed blocks which I want to open in the same time by clicking one button. I use `bootstrap 4 alpha 6`. I use next html but when I click button it open only first collapse block. The problem I cant use id to `data-target` cause the number of revealed blocks is dynamic, so I use class to these blocks. How to fix this problem?

**HTML:**

```
<button class="btn" type="button" data-parent="#blocks"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".block" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls=".block"></button>

<div id="blocks">
   <div class="collapse block" id="block-1">
      <!--FIRST BLOCK-->
   </div>
   <div class="collapse block" id="block-2">
      <!--SECOND BLOCK-->
   </div>
   <div class="collapse block" id="block-3">
      <!--THIRD BLOCK-->
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: any fiddle example ?

Comment: @rajamaha hello! Are you asking me to put my html to `jsfiddle.net` service?

Comment: yes sample code.you need to open all the boxes or any particular boxes

Comment: can i use jquery to open all box?

Comment: Sure, you can. I just thought this could be possible by bootstrap 4 js.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143163/discussion-between-maharajan-and-nurzhan-nogerbek).

Answer (score 1):

There is currently a bug in Alpha 6 that prevents multiple `data-target`s from working.

https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/21690

It will be fixed in the Beta release.

Comment: Thank you for this information. What is in this link exactly? I am little bit comfused.

Comment: It's a link to the bug report on Bootstrap's code repo (GitHub).